# Pandas to read csv file and grep the hostnames from a file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file which i'm trying to read with `pandas` based on the below code.

### Code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
data = pd.read_csv(input("Please input the CSV File Name: "), usecols=['Safe', 'Platform ID', 'Target system address']).dropna()
df = data[data['Platform ID'].str.startswith("TDS-Unix")][['Target system address', 'Safe' ]]
print(df)
```

### The above code I'm using as a script as follows:

```
$ ./getcbk_srvlist_1_1.py
Please input the CSV File Name: InventoryReport.csv
                  Target system address                          Safe

3                                host01     TDS-PAR-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
4                                host06          TDS-OT-SCM-UNIX-ROOT
5                                host09     TDS-PAR-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
```

The above is the sort of the output I have from my DataFrame, Now I'm looking a way a kind of grep the below host names from the `host_list.txt` file.

### Below is the host_list.txt

```
host01     
host02
host03
host04
host05
host06
host07
host08
host09
```

any ideas will be so helpful.

### Desired:

```
$./getcbk_srvlist_1_1.py | egrep "hosts044|hosts045"
InventoryReport.csv

52                     host044      TDS-OTT-DEFAULT-UNIX-Root
25238                  hosts045      TDS-DJ-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
```

Comment: Do you want to read another second file after you read the first csv?

Comment: @LudoSchmidt, I did not get it.

Comment: @dubbbdan, I need to search the hostnames in dataframe(df) from a file `host_list.txt`.

Comment: Do you want a pandas solution? Or do you really need to use egrep?  It is unclear to me how `df[''Target system address''] ` relates to the data in `host_list.txt`.  What information do you expect to get from `host_list.txt`?

Comment: @dubbbdan, I'm looking for pandas solution, However , I need to see if any names which is in `host_list.txt` matches with `df` output.

Comment: do you want to load in two files, and then filter your initial dataframe with the hostnames in the host_list.txt?

Comment: That will be fine.

Comment: you could do the following, pass the unique hostnames to a list, then filter your initial data with a `.loc.isin` `data.loc[data['Target system address'].isin(mylist)]`

Comment: @Datanovice,  that's what working on :-) , you spot on it.

Comment: any time buddy, happy coding :) don't forget to greentick the correct answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you after you create `df` you need to read in `host_list.txt` to another dataframe.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('host_list.txt',header=None)
df2.columns = ['host_list']


df2
Out[13]: 
  host_list
0    host01
1    host02
2    host03
3    host04
4    host05
5    host06
6    host07
7    host08
8    host09
```

If you then want to subset `df` based on the hosts in common with `df2`, you could use [`pandas.DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
df = df[df['Target system address'].isin(df2.host_list.unique())]
```

Which returns:

```
  Target system address                       Safe
0                host01  TDS-PAR-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
1                host06       TDS-OT-SCM-UNIX-ROOT
2                host09  TDS-PAR-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
```