# Pandas sort the unique group names and put the values under it from the datafarme result

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is an extension to my [earlier question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360361/pandas-to-read-csv-file-and-grep-the-hostnames-from-a-file) where I'm reading and csv file and then matching the values from another test file which is working fine.

### Working code:

```
#!/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(input("Please input the CSV File Name: "), usecols=['Safe', 'Platform ID', 'Target system address']).dropna()
df1 = data[data['Platform ID'].str.startswith("TDS-FL")][['Target system address', 'Safe' ]]
df2 = pd.read_csv('host_list.txt',header=None)
df2.columns = ['host_list']
df = df1[df1['Target system address'].isin(df2.host_list.unique())]
print(df)
```

Below is the resulted output from the above code.

### Output:

```
HOSTNAMES           GROUP 
--------------------------------------------- 
kfdaudet01          TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
kfdaudet02          TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
kfdaudet03          TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
kflggvt01           TDS-FL-SCM-UNIX-ROOT
kflggvt02           TDS-FL-SCM-UNIX-ROOT
kfvlgg01-sydney     TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
kfvlgg02-sydney     TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
kflba06vs01         TDS-FL-UNIX-ROOT
kflba07lo07         TDS-FL-UNIX-ROOT
```

From the above output I see many of the `HOSTNAMES` appearing under a Group So, group names are getting repeated.

However I'm looking to see if we can get the unique GROUP name and put the hostnames appearing for the group udder it as follows:

### Desired:

```
TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
------------------------
kfdaudet01
kfdaudet02
kfdaudet03

TDS-FL-SCM-UNIX-ROOT
---------------------
kflggvt01
kflggvt02
```

thank you for the help.

Comment: I think you original dataframe format is more organized

Comment: @Wen-Ben, Thanks for that, Just out of curiosity as I need the data in the desired format for the sake or current need :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could `stack` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df[df.columns[::-1]].sort_values('GROUP').stack().drop_duplicates(keep='first')

0  GROUP        TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
   HOSTNAMES                  kfdaudet01
1  HOSTNAMES                  kfdaudet02
2  HOSTNAMES                  kfdaudet03
5  HOSTNAMES             kfvlgg01-sydney
6  HOSTNAMES             kfvlgg02-sydney
3  GROUP            TDS-FL-SCM-UNIX-ROOT
   HOSTNAMES                   kflggvt01
4  HOSTNAMES                   kflggvt02
7  GROUP                TDS-FL-UNIX-ROOT
   HOSTNAMES                 kflba06vs01
8  HOSTNAMES                 kflba07lo07
```

or just create a list of dataframes from the group:

```
g = df.groupby('GROUP')
dfs = [group for _,group in g]
```

or create a `dict`:

```
d = {k:group for k,group in g}
# call group by group name
d['TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT']

         HOSTNAMES                     GROUP
0       kfdaudet01  TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
1       kfdaudet02  TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
2       kfdaudet03  TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
5  kfvlgg01-sydney  TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
6  kfvlgg02-sydney  TDS-FL-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
```

Comment: Groupby is the way to go for this kind of problem, you can iterate through the hostnames of a group while being able to get the name of the group you are currently iterating through.

Comment: @krock1516 Sure I would still recommend using `groupby` and probably store them in a `dict` rather than a list